# ¿Como importar un html dentro de otro html y use el mismo css del html padre?

Tags: css, html5

necesito saber como puedo importar un html ya que el html principal tiene varias secciones que se repiten y pense en pasar esa secciones a otro html y despues importarlas donde los necesite, como puedo importarlos? he intentado importalos con Iframe pero no utiliza el css de la pagina principal

PD. estoy utilizando puro html 5 puro

Comment: solo con html no se puede por que html no es un lenguaje de programacion, lo debes hacer con ajax usando JavaScript

Comment: @John y como lo puedo hacer asi?

Comment: pon en google  "uso de ajax" y te mostrara mas de un tutorial de como se hace

Answer (score 1):

Hay un truco muy feo, pero quizas puede servirte.

Digamos que tienes en un html externo, un div que quieres repetir

```
<div>Esta es una prueba</div>
```

Creas un archivo javascritpt, ejemplo: "divitem.js" y pones

```
const DIV_ITEM = `<div>Esta es una prueba</div>`
```

Las comillas invertidas, que están al principio y al final del html sirven para crear [Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
Cualquier editor moderno te permitirá seguir operando el html como tal y no como string.

En tu html principal pones esto

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="~/divitem.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

   <script>document.write(DIV_ITEM)</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Puedes poner tantos document.write(DIV_ITEM) como quieras y donde quieras.